# Entity Framework Code First One-To-Many Relation Mapping with link table

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a question about One-To-Many relationship between two tables when there is the link (join) table between.

Example tables:

```
ChildTable:
ID int NOT NULL PK
Relation int NOT NULL

ParentTable:
ID int NOT NULL PK
Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL

ParentChildren:
ParentTable_ID int NOT NULL PFK
ChildTable_ID int NOT NULL PFK
```

Entities:

```
public class ChildTable
{
    public ChildTable()
    {
        this.ParentTables = new List<ParentTable>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }       
    public int Relation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ParentTable> ParentTables { get; set; }
}

public class ParentTable
{
    public ParentTable()
    {
        this.ChildTables = new List<ChildTable>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildTable> ChildTables { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class ChildTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChildTable>
{
    public ChildTableMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ChildTable");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Relation).HasColumnName("Relation");
    }
}
public class ParentTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ParentTable>
{
    public ParentTableMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ParentTable");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.ChildTables)
            .WithMany(t => t.ParentTables)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("ParentChildren");
                    m.MapLeftKey("ParentTable_ID");
                    m.MapRightKey("ChildTable_ID");
                });

    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    static TestContext()
    { 
        Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<ChildTable> ChildTables { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParentTable> ParentTables { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChildTableMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ParentTableMap());
    }
}
```

Code to add the child and parent:

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
                var parent = new ParentTable { Name = "Mother Goose" };                   
                var child = new ChildTable { Relation = 1 };                   
                context.ParentTables.Add(parent);
                context.ChildTables.Add(child);
                parent.ChildTables.Add(child);
                context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

And all works as expected, but I really have only 1 parent and many children.

How to do the mapping that includes writing to the link table (with changed ChildTable class that does not have the ICollection of ParentTable)?

Comment: Do you have this existing table structure and cannot change it? I'm wondering because for one-to-many relationship you usually could drop the join table and introduce a FK column in the ChildTable. I guess you cannot change your tables for some reason, right?

Comment: Yes, it would be quite easy without that link table, but unfortunately, this link table can not be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to define such a mapping. Join tables are only for many-to-many relationships. You have to keep in mind that your database schema (which you cannot change, as you said in the comments to your question) already defines a many-to-many relationship. For example these two entries...

```
ParentTable_ID:  1    2
ChildTable_ID:   1    1
```

...are valid entries in the `ParentChildren` table, they don't violate the PK constraint and they say that child 1 has the two parents 1 and 2.

If your business logic only allows that a child can have only one single parent, the database schema is modeled wrong. You cannot fix this flaw with EF.

A possible workaround might be to ensure in your business logic in your code that the `ParentTables` collection of your `ChildTable` entity never has more than one element, perhaps by introducing a not mapped helper property:

```
public class ChildTable
{
    public ChildTable()
    {
        this.ParentTables = new List<ParentTable>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }       
    public int Relation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ParentTable> ParentTables { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] // or use .Ignore(c => c.ParentTable) in Fluent API
    public ParentTable ParentTable
    {
        get
        {
            return ParentTables.SingleOrDefault();
            // let is crash if there is more than one element in the list
        }

        set
        {
            var oldParent = ParentTables.SingleOrDefault();
            if (oldParent != value)
            {
                ParentTables.Clear();
                if (value != null)
                    ParentTables.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's only a little help if you only use the `ParentTable` property. You have to avoid to use the collection and add more than one parent. You cannot make it `private` because it must be mapped. It's also not safe on the other side of the relationship. You could write: `parent1.ChildTables.Add(child1); parent2.ChildTables.Add(child1);` which would lead to two parents for `child1` in the database. You could catch this by writing helper methods for adding a child on the `ParentTable` entity which check if the added child doesn't already have a parent other than `this` parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry I cann't vote up for the answer, I do not have enough points.