# Entity Framework Code First One-To-Many Relation Mapping with link table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

Is there a way to map one-to-many relationship between two tables that have the link (join) table in between?

Comment: I found your old question better, at least it provides more context: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7064796/270591

Comment: Correct, but there was no response. I can not believe that this scenario is so rare.

Comment: Make a small change in your old question to push the question up on top of active questions. I'd consider this as a better way than creating exactly the same question again but with much less context. Or better: Provide additional info and clarifications in your old questions which might improve your chance to get an answer.

Comment: I actually thought that maybe in that question I gave to much detail and that simple question might prompt for more responses.

Comment: Maybe, too much detail is bad sometimes. (I don't think that your old question has too much.) But this time you have really too little detail :). Btw, I've taken a look at your old question again.

Comment: Thank you for taking a time. But looks to me that the best approach would be to drop the link tables. I would try to see if there is any chance of dropping them. I do not have a lot of experience in database design and my previous suggestion to get away from link tables in one-to-many relationships and introducing the foreign key instead was not accepted.

Comment: I am not very experienced with DB design too. But I can say for sure that it's pretty standard to model a one-to-many relationship with a FK column in the children table and not with a link table. Quite weird, that your proposal has been rejected.

Comment: @Slauma So how does change in the active question work? I have edited the question I asked almost a month ago that still has no answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872483/entity-framework-mapping), but it did not get pushed on top of active questions

Comment: I can just see your question as the fifth question (if I select by entity-framework-4.1 tag) in the list of "active" questions. (You must really use the "active" tab in the question list, not the "newest" tab, did you?)

Comment: @Slauma. Thank you, I was looking in the Unanswered tab (should have read my own question - i did write active, but it was more logical (to me) to look at unanswered))

Comment: I think the "Unanswered" questions are sorted descending by number of votes to the question. Editing a question doesn't change this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you have a join table for a one-to-many relationship? All you need is a foreign key from one to the other. A join table is only necessary for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: You are quite right, but I do have that link table in between.

Comment: Well if you already have an existing database model, why are you using code-first? Code-first is meant for a situation where you want to create your database from scratch **based on your object model**, and will create your database based on the best way to support your object model. What you're trying to do is NOT the best way to support your object model.

Comment: So which approach would you suggest? I did start with the database first, but found that code first allows for more flexibility. This is the new project and has new database, although database and the code has been developed at the same time, there are some differences (one of them being that if there is either one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, link table is created).

Comment: @Minnie: Code-First, Database-First, Model-First doesn't matter for your problem. You just cannot define a one-to-many mapping with a join table in between in the database, neither in Code (annotations, Fluent API) nor in an EDMX file. If you let EF create the model from the database you likely get a many-to-many mapping.

Comment: I was thinking which approach would Joel suggest regardless of one-to-many relationship problem, because that was not the reason I moved to Code First, but this should probably require asking another question. Thank you both for your time.

Comment: Well the obvious reason is that nullable foreign keys are a design flaw.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, the one-to-many relationship is just a particular case of the many-to-many. Using the code (first) approach, we can do exactly the same, defining a simplified version of a many-to-many relationship.
Using the very same example used in the [Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), and assuming the one-to-many relation from `Student` to `Course`, we would have:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course() { }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

// We don't need this side of the relationship
//  public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

...

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses)
                .WithMany(/* c => c.Students */)  // 'WithMany' goes empty
                .Map(c => {
                     c.MapLeftKey("Student_id");
                     c.MapRightKey("Course_id");
                     c.ToTable("StudentAndCourse");
                 });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```